# htaccess hash url redirection to without hash issue with hyphens

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I'm facing url (hash) redirecting issue in my angular application. I tried fixing it with angular way but it doesn't work so I go with custom .htaccess way. This solution is working fine but I'm facing issue with (duplicate) URL(s) which have hyphen(s). Example below.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/terms    http://example.com/#terms
RedirectMatch 301 ^/terms-bb http://example.com/#terms-bb
```

As per above example if open "http://example.com/terms-bb" it redirects to "/terms" instead. So is there any way that I can strictly match these duplicate urls?

Comment: You only anchored your patterns at the start there, so `^/terms` matches on anything that _starts with_ `/terms`. If you want a strict match, then anchor it at the end as well –  `^/terms$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only anchored your patterns at the start there, so `^/terms` matches on anything that *starts with* `/terms`.

If you want a strict match, then anchor it at the end as well – `^/terms$`.